# RStudio will not load latest version of R

Tags: r, rstudio

Usually RStudio will load the latest version of R when I download it from CRAN. Now I cannot get RStudio to update from R 4.2.2 to R 4.2.3.

I downloaded latest version of R from Repository into my files and it appeared there.

Comment: "I downloaded" Have you installed it? You can select a specific R version in  the RStudio menu under "Tools" --> "Global Options" but the R version has to be installed on your system. By default, with Windows, RStudio uses the R version that is registered, which requires installation with admin rights, but you can select a different R installation manually.

Answer (score 0):

After you open your project, RStudio Pro is loaded.

You can then change the R version from the top right corner and see the available ones.

R 4.2.3 is available

[image: pic2]

[image: pic1]